# Redirection of process created with platform invoke

Tags: c#, .net, winapi, pinvoke, io-redirection

I create and control a process by platform invoke since C# still does not allow to create suspended process and so on. Having a process created that way I can create instance of Process .Net class if it's needed. But I need to redirect output of the child process. It's easy to implement creating process using Diagnostics namespace, but it is impossible to do if process already created. It's also possible to do in pure C++. But to create pipes, to redirect children process output and to make asynchronous I/O using p/invoke seems insane. Does exist more simple solution of this problem?

Comment: What exactly you want to do ? Why do you not try to use pinvoke and see what you get?

Comment: Write a C++/CLI mixed mode assembly to do this

Comment: You will have to do it the "insane" way, no alternative for that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1 day later...
Now I have next smelling classes in my project for the process spawn with the output redirection. I've decided to implement the redirection just to a file for beginning.

```
public class Program
{
    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        using (var mp = ProcessManipulator.Start("test1.exe", null,
            ProcessCreationFlags.CREATE_BREAKAWAY_FROM_JOB | 
            ProcessCreationFlags.CREATE_SUSPENDED, null, "5.txt"))
        {
            mp.Resume();
        }
    }
}

[Flags]
public enum ProcessCreationFlags : uint
{
    ZERO_FLAG = 0x00000000,
    CREATE_BREAKAWAY_FROM_JOB = 0x01000000,
    CREATE_DEFAULT_ERROR_MODE = 0x04000000,
    CREATE_NEW_CONSOLE = 0x00000010,
    CREATE_NEW_PROCESS_GROUP = 0x00000200,
    CREATE_NO_WINDOW = 0x08000000,
    CREATE_PROTECTED_PROCESS = 0x00040000,
    CREATE_PRESERVE_CODE_AUTHZ_LEVEL = 0x02000000,
    CREATE_SEPARATE_WOW_VDM = 0x00001000,
    CREATE_SHARED_WOW_VDM = 0x00001000,
    CREATE_SUSPENDED = 0x00000004,
    CREATE_UNICODE_ENVIRONMENT = 0x00000400,
    DEBUG_ONLY_THIS_PROCESS = 0x00000002,
    DEBUG_PROCESS = 0x00000001,
    DETACHED_PROCESS = 0x00000008,
    EXTENDED_STARTUPINFO_PRESENT = 0x00080000,
    INHERIT_PARENT_AFFINITY = 0x00010000
}

public class ProcessManipulator : IDisposable
{
    private IntPtr _primaryThread;
    private bool _disposed = false;

    private ProcessManipulator(IntPtr primaryThread)
    {
        _primaryThread = primaryThread;
    }

    public Process ManipulatedProcess { get; private set; }

    [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
    private struct PROCESS_INFORMATION
    {
        public IntPtr hProcess;
        public IntPtr hThread;
        public int dwProcessId;
        public int dwThreadId;
    }

    [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
    private struct SECURITY_ATTRIBUTES
    {
        public UInt32 nLength;
        public IntPtr lpSecurityDescriptor;
        public Int32 bInheritHandle;
    }

    [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential, CharSet = CharSet.Unicode)]
    private struct STARTUPINFO
    {
        public Int32 cb;
        public string lpReserved;
        public string lpDesktop;
        public string lpTitle;
        public Int32 dwX;
        public Int32 dwY;
        public Int32 dwXSize;
        public Int32 dwYSize;
        public Int32 dwXCountChars;
        public Int32 dwYCountChars;
        public Int32 dwFillAttribute;
        public Int32 dwFlags;
        public Int16 wShowWindow;
        public Int16 cbReserved2;
        public IntPtr lpReserved2;
        public IntPtr hStdInput;
        public IntPtr hStdOutput;
        public IntPtr hStdError;
    }

    [DllImport("kernel32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
    private static extern bool CreateProcess(string lpApplicationName, string lpCommandLine, IntPtr lpProcessAttributes,
        IntPtr lpThreadAttributes,
        bool bInheritHandles, uint dwCreationFlags, IntPtr lpEnvironment,
        string lpCurrentDirectory, ref STARTUPINFO lpStartupInfo, out PROCESS_INFORMATION lpProcessInformation);

    [DllImport("kernel32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
    private static extern bool CloseHandle(IntPtr hObject);

    /// <summary>
    /// Decrements a thread's suspend count. When the suspend count is decremented to zero, the execution of the thread is resumed.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="hThread">A handle to the thread to be restarted.</param>
    /// <returns>If the function succeeds, the return value is the thread's previous suspend count. If the function fails, the return value is -1.</returns>
    [DllImport("kernel32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
    private static extern int ResumeThread(IntPtr hThread);

    public void Resume()
    {
        if (ResumeThread(_primaryThread) == -1)
            throw new Exception(string.Format("Unable to resume the thread.  Error: {0}", Marshal.GetLastWin32Error()));
    }

    [DllImport("kernel32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Auto, CallingConvention = CallingConvention.StdCall, SetLastError = true)]
    public static extern IntPtr CreateFile(
        string lpFileName,
        uint dwDesiredAccess,
        uint dwShareMode,
        IntPtr SecurityAttributes,
        uint dwCreationDisposition,
        uint dwFlagsAndAttributes,
        IntPtr hTemplateFile
    );

    private const int GENERIC_WRITE = 0x40000000;
    private const int FILE_SHARE_READ = 0x00000001;
    private const int FILE_SHARE_WRITE = 2;
    private const int CREATE_NEW = 1;
    private const int FILE_ATTRIBUTE_NORMAL = 128;
    private static IntPtr INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE = new IntPtr(-1);

    private static IntPtr PrepareLogFile(string fileName)
    {
        var length = Marshal.SizeOf(typeof(SECURITY_ATTRIBUTES));
        var securityAttributes = new SECURITY_ATTRIBUTES()
        {
            nLength = (uint)length,
            lpSecurityDescriptor = IntPtr.Zero,
            bInheritHandle = 1
        };

        var securityAttributesPtr = Marshal.AllocHGlobal(length);
        try
        {
            Marshal.StructureToPtr(securityAttributes, securityAttributesPtr, false);
            var hLogFile = CreateFile(fileName,
                GENERIC_WRITE,
                FILE_SHARE_READ | FILE_SHARE_WRITE,
                securityAttributesPtr,
                CREATE_NEW,
                FILE_ATTRIBUTE_NORMAL,
                IntPtr.Zero);
            if (hLogFile == INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE)
                throw new Exception(string.Format("Unable to create a log file.  Error: {0}", Marshal.GetLastWin32Error()));
            return hLogFile;
        }
        finally
        {
            Marshal.FreeHGlobal(securityAttributesPtr);
        }
    }

    [Flags]
    private enum STARTF : uint
    {
        STARTF_USESHOWWINDOW = 0x00000001,
        STARTF_USESIZE = 0x00000002,
        STARTF_USEPOSITION = 0x00000004,
        STARTF_USECOUNTCHARS = 0x00000008,
        STARTF_USEFILLATTRIBUTE = 0x00000010,
        STARTF_RUNFULLSCREEN = 0x00000020,  // ignored for non-x86 platforms
        STARTF_FORCEONFEEDBACK = 0x00000040,
        STARTF_FORCEOFFFEEDBACK = 0x00000080,
        STARTF_USESTDHANDLES = 0x00000100,
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Allows to create child process specifing creation flags.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="fileName">Path to the executable module</param>
    /// <param name="args">Arguments</param>
    /// <param name="creationFlags">Process creation flags</param>
    /// <param name="currentDirectory">Current directory</param>
    /// <param name="logFileName">File for output redirection</param>
    public static ProcessManipulator Start(string fileName, string args, ProcessCreationFlags creationFlags,
        string currentDirectory, string logFileName)
    {
        var hLogFile = PrepareLogFile(logFileName);
        try
        {
            return Start(fileName, args, creationFlags, currentDirectory, hLogFile);
        }
        finally
        {
            CloseHandle(hLogFile);
        }
    }

    private static ProcessManipulator Start(string fileName, string args, ProcessCreationFlags creationFlags, string currentDirectory, IntPtr hOutRedirection)
    {
        var startupInfo = new STARTUPINFO
        {
            cb = Marshal.SizeOf(typeof(STARTUPINFO)),
            hStdError = hOutRedirection,
            hStdOutput = hOutRedirection,
            dwFlags = hOutRedirection != IntPtr.Zero ? (int)STARTF.STARTF_USESTDHANDLES : 0
        };

        var processInfo = new PROCESS_INFORMATION();

        if (!CreateProcess(fileName,
            String.Format("{0} {1}", Path.GetFileName(fileName), args),
            IntPtr.Zero,
            IntPtr.Zero,
            hOutRedirection != IntPtr.Zero,
            (uint)creationFlags,
            IntPtr.Zero,
            currentDirectory,
            ref startupInfo,
            out processInfo))
            throw new Exception(string.Format("Unable to create a process.  Error: {0}", Marshal.GetLastWin32Error()));

        //GetProcessById() open new handle for the process so current must be closed as useless
        if (!CloseHandle(processInfo.hProcess))
            throw new Exception(string.Format("Unable to close the process handle.  Error: {0}", Marshal.GetLastWin32Error()));

        return new ProcessManipulator(processInfo.hThread)
        {
            ManipulatedProcess = Process.GetProcessById(processInfo.dwProcessId)
        };
    }

    public void Dispose()
    {
        Dispose(true);
        GC.SuppressFinalize(this);
    }

    private void Dispose(bool disposing)
    {
        if (_disposed)
            return;

        if (disposing)
        {
            //dispose managed disposable resources
            ManipulatedProcess.Dispose();
        }

        var result = CloseHandle(_primaryThread);
        _primaryThread = IntPtr.Zero;
        //if (!result)
        //  throw new Exception(string.Format("Unable to close the job object handle.  Error: {0}", Marshal.GetLastWin32Error()));

        _disposed = true;
    }

    ~ProcessManipulator()
    {
        Dispose(false);
    }
}
```

And the code of test "child" app:

```
public static void Main(string[] args)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Test");
}
```

File is created and contains string "Test".